# Fetch all the hyperlinks from a webpage and recursively doing that in java

Tags: java, regex, recursion

```
1 .Fetch all contents from a Webpage
2. fetch hyperlinks from the webpage.
3. Repeat the 1 & 2 from the fetched hyperlink
4. repeat the process untill 200 hyperlinks regietered or no more hyperlink to fetch.
```

I wrote a sample programs but due to poor understanding of recursion , my loop became an infinite loop.
Suggest me to solve the code matching the expectation.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Content
{
    private static final String HTML_A_HREF_TAG_PATTERN = 
        "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
    Pattern pattern;
    public Content ()
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(HTML_A_HREF_TAG_PATTERN);
    }

    private void fetchContentFromURL(String strLink) {
        String content = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
          connection =  new URL(strLink).openConnection();
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
          scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
          content = scanner.next();
        }catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        fetchURL(content);
    }

    private void fetchURL ( String content )
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( content );
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            if(group.toLowerCase().contains( "http" ) || group.toLowerCase().contains( "https" )) {
            group = group.substring( group.indexOf( "=" )+1 );
            group = group.replaceAll( "'", "" );
            group = group.replaceAll( "\"", "" );
            System.out.println("lINK "+group);
            fetchContentFromURL(group);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {

        new Content().fetchContentFromURL( "http://www.google.co.in" );
    }

}
```

I am open for any other solution as well but want to stick with core java Api only no 3rd party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option here is to remember all visited links to avoid cyclic paths. Here's how to archive it with additional Set storage for already visited links:

```
public class Content {
private static final String HTML_A_HREF_TAG_PATTERN =
        "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
private Pattern pattern;
private Set<String> visitedUrls = new HashSet<String>();

public Content() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(HTML_A_HREF_TAG_PATTERN);
}

private void fetchContentFromURL(String strLink) {
    String content = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new URL(strLink).openConnection();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            content = scanner.next();
            visitedUrls.add(strLink);
            fetchURL(content);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void fetchURL(String content) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group();
        if (group.toLowerCase().contains("http") || group.toLowerCase().contains("https")) {
            group = group.substring(group.indexOf("=") + 1);
            group = group.replaceAll("'", "");
            group = group.replaceAll("\"", "");
            System.out.println("lINK " + group);
            if (!visitedUrls.contains(group) && visitedUrls.size() < 200) {
                fetchContentFromURL(group);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("DONE");
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Content().fetchContentFromURL("http://www.google.co.in");
}

}
```

I also fixed some other issues in fetching logic, now it works as expected.

Comment: You're always welcome. I've also updated the code to include 200 links limitation

Answer (score 1):

inside the fetchContentFromURL method you should record which url u r currently fetching, and if that url has already be fetched then skip it. otherwise two page A, B, which has a link point to each other will cause your code keep fetching.

Comment: yeah.so I added all the url inside a Set , so only if set returns true I am fetching else no , but hyow to exit the entire operation , like when there is no go for urls , so program must exist

Comment: 2 possible solutions. Just inside the fetchContentFromURL method, get the size of the Set and compare with your expectation before each request. if the size of the set is larger then your expectation, call System.exit(0) to exit the whole program, or just return null from the method, and without no new page and url is fetching the program will also exit finally.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to JK1's answer, for achieving target 4 of your question, you might want to maintain the count of hyperlinks as instance variable. A rough pseudo code might be(you can adjust the exact count. Also as an alternate, you can use HashSet length to know the number of Hyperlinks your program has parsed till now):

```
if (!visitedUrls.contains(group) && noOfHyperlinksVisited++ < 200) {
            fetchContentFromURL(group);
}
```

However, I was not sure whether you want a total of 200 hyperlinks OR want to traverse to a depth of 200 links from starting page. In case it is later, you might wish to explore [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which will let you know when you have reached your target depth.